# Using an Azure Function in conjunction with SharePoint

Tags: python, azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I'm getting excels uploaded to my teams SharePoint folder daily and I've written a python script to parse them and insert them into our database. Can I use a Azure Logic App with an Azure function to automate that process? I'm not sure how to incorporate SharePoint and access the source files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Flow:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/flow/get-started/create-your%20first-flow

Then use HTTP Request to trigger your Azure Function:

https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/01/27/integrating-microsoft-flow-with-azure-functions-for-non-it-people/